# Is it possible to make the Windows 8 Metro App listbox behave just like the Windows Phone listbox version?

Tags: xaml, windows-8, winrt-xaml

I'm using a ListBox to display some items in my Windows 8 App.

I would like to pan it down just in like I do it in the Windows Phone version: click anywhere and drag up or down. Also, it would be nice to see the scroll only when the items are in movement (again, like the windows phone version).

How can I achieve that?

Comment: You can do all that with templating.  Are you having specific issues with doing that?

Comment: You should run your app in the simulator and change the action/tool (on the right side of simulator) to be hand to simulate what the app would look like when using touch. I believe the ListBox will behave as you request when doing this.